# ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution org.sonar.java.AnalysisException:

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

While running Sonar Scanner in simple hello word through Azure pipeline and SonarQube getting below error.

Your project contains .java files, please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries
property, or exclude them from the analysis with sonar.exclusions property.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the requested parameters on the Prepare step in the Advanced section:

[image]

Detailed explanation of the parameters you can find here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/java/